# How to disable VSCode Markdown Preview sync

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to toggle off/on the synchronized scrolling in the Markdown Preview of VSCode?

Sometimes I need to view different parts of the *same* markdown file in multiple panes (i.e. editing a summary table at one end of the file, while scrolling through the remaining file in another editor to review details at the start, or middle of the file). If I also have the preview open to review how my table looks, and scroll that, then *all the editors will scroll to match the position of the preview*.  I understand that this *is* the intended behavior, but in this case with multiple editors on the same file at different places, it breaks my workflow because now they all show the same part of the file. I can no longer view different parts at the same time.

I'd like to turn this off occasionally when the automatic scroll interferes with multiple views of the same document in different editors.

Answer (score 0):

There are two settings which control synchronized scrolling between the Markdown Preview, and the editors:

- `markdown.preview.scrollEditorWithPreview` - When a Markdown preview is scrolled, update the view of the editor(s)
- `markdown.preview.scrollPreviewWithEditorSelection` - When a Markdown editor is scrolled, update the view of the preview

These can be set to `true`/`false` in the `settings.json` for global or workspace settings, or you can set/clear the check-boxes in the Settings UI (search for `markdown.preview.scroll`

It would be nice to have a command to bind to a keyboard shortcut, but I don't see one in the command palette.